# Customize Radar Chart LiveChart MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, livecharts

I'm using LiveChart to create a Radar Chart, that now i would like customize.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfKkW.png)

1. How can I add BackgroundColor just in the yellow signed parts?
2. How can I change the circle form of the chart? I would the sharper corner like signed in red

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.